# How to do you store data to Google Drive using console.cloud.google

Tags: google-drive-api, google-cloud-storage, gcloud

In my google console it says here [Cloud Storage pricing](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing?_ga=2.223811864.-2010855043.1571122466)

that the price for standard storage is $.026 per gigabyte month, which I think means that 500 gigs stored during one month will cost $13 since 500 * .026 = 13.  But this article [The Google Drive Price Cut Changes The Game For Personal Cloud Storage](https://readwrite.com/2014/03/17/google-drive-pricing-plans-drop-cloud-rivals-breakdown/) says:

> Google is making a terabyte of cloud storage available for just $10

I don't see where you upload data to Google drive at [Google cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/).

My second question is that I want to make sure that I can create a virtual instance and connect it to Google drive or Storage and read the data from it and put that data into the RAM of the virtual instance.

Comment: google cloud console is not google drive what exactly are you doing?   Google cloud storage has nothing to do with google drive.

Comment: Also, that article is from 2014, I really wouldn't rely on it.

Answer (score 2):

## [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/)

is a web application which works as a file store allowing users to store files. Communication with it is normally done though the web application itself however developers can use the Google drive api to interact with google drive programticlly.

You may want to go though the documentation on the [Google drive api](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk) to understand what its capable of.

## [Google cloud storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/)

is designed as a Unified object storage for developers and enterprises Cloud Storage allows world-wide storage and retrieval of any amount of data at any time. You can use Cloud Storage for a range of scenarios including serving website content, storing data for archival and disaster recovery, or distributing large data objects to users via direct download.

Interaction with this is done primarrly though the cloud console and command line tools.

> I don't see where you upload data to Google drive at Google cloud console.

You dont cloud console wont help you upload to google drive.

> My second question is that I want to make sure that I can create a virtual instance and connect it to Google drive or Storage and read the data from it and put that data into the RAM of the virtual instance.

Google drive is a web application you cant create a virtual instance of that.

You might want to go though a few of the quickstarts to understand how Google cloud console and the command line tool work [Quick Starts](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/quickstarts)

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate that.